# I want to create a .html file in /public folder of Laravel

Tags: php, fopen, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to create and store some HTML code from a textarea into a file

`fopen` method in PHP will create a file if that file doesn't exist already but it is not working in Laravel 5.7

Here is my demo code

```
$plugin_html_file_nm = "plugin_html".time().".html";
$html_plugin = fopen("/public/plugin_html_storage/".$plugin_html_file_nm,"w");
fwrite($html_plugin,$request->input('plugin_html'));
$plugin->plugin_html = $plugin_html_file_nm;
```

This error is given `fopen(/public/plugin_html_storage/plugin_html1546535810.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does directory `/public/plugin_html_storage` exist?

Comment: no that folder is not exist

Comment: Then you are having a wrong path in your code. Take a look at answers, there is a solution given to you.

Comment: Most of the time, "I want to have PHP write a .html file" indicates a misunderstanding of how PHP apps are typically created. Could you elaborate on *why* you want to do this?

Comment: i am create a project related to this @ceejayoz i cant elaborate anything else.....

Answer (score 3):

Laravel provides a helper `public_path()`

> The public_path function returns the fully qualified path to the
>   public directory. You may also use the public_path function to
>   generate a fully qualified path to a given file within the public
>   directory

Maybe you need to add the full path. So:

```
$html_plugin = fopen(public_path("plugin_html_storage/.$plugin_html_file_nm"),"w");
```

Also, make sure you have writing privilegies. As the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) states:

> The file must be accessible to PHP, so you need to ensure that the file access permissions allow this access.

Answer (score 0):

Your laravel app by default is served from the public directory.

So in order to achieve what you're trying to do, replace

```
$html_plugin = fopen("/public/plugin_html_storage/".$plugin_html_file_nm,"w");
```

with:

```
$html_plugin = fopen("./plugin_html_storage/".$plugin_html_file_nm, "w");
```

Note: The **plugin_html_storage** directory should be created in the **public** directory so the operation doesn't fail.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the relative path.

```
$html_plugin = fopen("../public/plugin_html_storage/".$plugin_html_file_nm,"w");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents(public_path()."plugin_html".time().".html", 
$request->input('plugin_html'));
```